# header function not working with exit in PHP

Tags: php

I have a header function inside another function, but the thing is that it doesn't work with exit, even though it works fine without exit. Without exit, it redirects to test2.php just fine, but with exit in there, it doesn't redirect at all.

```
<?php

function goTo($string){

header("Location:".$string);
exit;

}

goTo("test2.php")

?>
```

Comment: technically, it should be `Location:[space]`. you're missing the space, and in general haven't provided enough detail. checked for things like "headers already sent"?

Comment: @MarcB RFC 2616 says a space is preferred after the colon, but it's not required.

Comment: @MarcB It has worked for months without the space on my last server.

Comment: As he said, check your PHP error log for the "Headers already sent" warning.

Comment: "last server"? So in other words, nothing's changed, except you moved from one city into another into a completely different place... but that doesn't matter because it's still your stuff.

Comment: I think the name 'goTo' may also cause a conflict as it is a reserved name now. But I am not sure because the exact keyword is 'goto'. (All lower-cased.)

Comment: @MarcB We're talking about the space, not what else has changed. The space is obviously not required as it worked months without it, but obviously you still seem to think that you're right.

Comment: `goTo("test2.php")` where's the semi-colon? The function is not even going to be called.

Comment: @developerwjk The semicolon is next to location.

Comment: what? PHP is not VB. You pretty much need a semicolon on every line, minus a few exceptions (like control structures).

Comment: @developerwjk What are you talking about? The semicolon is clearly in the function.

Comment: So the function *call* doesn't need a semi-colon too? Is this PHP or VB?

Comment: @developerwjk You mean goTo: ("test2.php")?

Comment: right. If this code is really all you have, it'll work, but if you have another line without a semicolon like that, you'll get a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```
<?php

function UrlGo($string){

header("Location: $string");
exit;

};

UrlGo("http://google.com")

?>
```